# SSRS report losing formatting in interactive viewer

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have an SSRS report with two subreports that had been working fine.  Recently I added some additional table sections to the report and I started seeing an issue when the report was displayed in the interactive viewer.  The data is fine but the formatting on the last two table sections does not appear in the viewer.

The formatting actually stops working half way through the next to last report.  However, when I print the report (or export to a PDF), all of the formatting is there and the report prints fine.

I have tried splitting the report into more subreports, running with different data and it still does not display correctly in the interactive viewer.  The report and subreports do have a lot of formatting and table sections and I am wondering if the RDL files are too big to store in memory or if they even do get stored in memory.

The RDL file sizes are 61 kB for the main report and 2612 kB and 2608 kB respectively for the subreports.  Is there a size limitation on the RDL files?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I have found a work around for my problem.  If I render my report directly to a PDF, then the report will not display in the interactive viewer, but only as a PDF which displays correctly.  This is done by adding "&rs:Format=PDF" to my URL when I call it from my C# program that allows the user to input the parameters.  Then the user can print the report and never see the missing formatting in the interactive viewer.  This works for my, however, I would still like to know if there is another answer that allows it to view correctly in the interactive viewer or if I have surpassed some memory limitations.

Answer (score 0):

If you split the report into its component parts does it display ok? If as you say you have recently added some new sections/Sub reports to it if you remove them does it look ok again.

You have probably got some strange overlapping happening, in the report designer when the report complies check the warning tag to see if it gives you any clues

Comment: I have split the report into smaller sub-reports with the part that does not display correctly in one sub-report.  Then when I move the parts that did not display correctly up in the order, that section displays fine.  However, the new section at the bottom does not display correctly.  I have recoded the whole section that was an issue and that did not fix it.  Also, I looked specifically at the related xml and there were not issues with overlap or missing tags.